# extjs null data should load empty grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

When the user select an item with info (json), the grid renders as expected.

But, when the returned data is null or {"total":0,"Products":null}, the grid keeps the previous selection.

The page is [here](http://pssnet.com/~devone/dnc/dncEditProducts2.php):

If the returned data is null, I need it to render it empty.

I am loading the grid as below:

```
    ProductsEditDataStore.baseParams.ProductTypeID =  ProductTypeID;
       ProductsEditDataStore.load({params:{start:0, limit:12}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use an empty array instead of null:

```
{"total":0,"Products":[]}
```